# operator overloading("<<"):why the “cout” did not work properly?

Tags: c++

I am learning operator overloading recently. I don't know why `cout` is outputting nothing after I add `const` keyword for `ostream`  in argument list. Does this have something to do with the addition of that keyword? the code is as follows:

**Program1:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
private:
    string bar;
public:
    Foo(string str);
    friend  const ostream& operator<<(const ostream& o, const Foo& f);
};

Foo::Foo(string str)
{
    this->bar = str;
}
const ostream&  operator<<(const ostream& o, const Foo& f)
{
    o << f.bar;
    return o;
}
int main()
{
    Foo f("HelloWorld");
    cout << f;
}
```

**output**:nothing

**Program2** :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>


using namespace std;

class Foo
{
private:
    string bar;
public:
    Foo(string str);
    friend  ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Foo& f);


};

Foo::Foo(string str)
{
    this->bar = str;
}
ostream&  operator<<(ostream& o, const Foo& f)
{
    o << f.bar;
    return o;
}
int main()
{
    Foo f("HelloWorld");
    cout << f;
}
```

**output**:HelloWorld

Comment: Is there any difference in these two samples? At least I can't spot one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You are looking in wrong way. Here is the difference in return type and argument type.

Comment: I'm pretty surprised the first one compiles. `o<<f.bar;` should be a non-const operation. With clang++, I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't spot the `const ostream&` in the 1st sample. Clearly that won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by `const`. Declare your friend function as non-const:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Foo& f);
```

And implementation:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Foo& f)
{
    o << f.bar;
    return o;
}
```

I can't understand why does this code compile because `operator<<` should always change the object. Your code is an **undefined behaviour** and may cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: "Nothing" is as valid as a segfault when it comes to UB.

Comment: @Quentin Is this UB? I thought here it is caused by writing to `const` object and it is always a segmentation fault (attempt to writing to read-only chunk of memory), am I right?

Comment: Nope ! `const` is a compile-time security, but does not force the compiler to store the object in read-only memory (which might not even exist on the destination platform). In this particular case even, the `const&` gives the function a read-only view of `std::cout`, but of course `std::cout` itself is not in read-only memory. Hence, undefined behaviour : it might happen to work, crash, or something else. The segfault has probably been caused by a wild UB-enabled optimization.

Comment: @Quentin thanks much for the explanation! I'll update my answer then.